# What is the difference between て phrase ending verbs and nominalized verb-stem phrase ending verbs?

Tags: grammar

For example in the sentence 政府は学校や病院を建設し、教師や医療スタッフの訓練も始めた。What's the difference in the first phrase ending in 建設し rather than 建設して?

Answer (score -1):

Apparently the verb stem form is more literary/formal and the te form more spoken/informal